# Erro 1053 o serviço não respondeu à requisição de início ou controle em tempo hábil

Tags: c#, windows, windows-service

Olá! Fiz um serviço windows de envio e e-mails, porém estou obtendo o erro 1053 ao tentar iniciar ele. Olhei vários artigos e forums e não consegui resolver o problema. Alguém saberia me explicar o que poderia ser? Segue o código.

Servico.cs

```
    public partial class EnvioEmailAutomatico : ServiceBase
{
    private int eventId = 1;
    private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;

    public EnvioEmailAutomatico()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 300000; // 5 Minutos
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Serviço de Envio de E-mail Automático Encerrado.");
    }

    public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Monitorando os E-mails Agendados", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId++);
    }
```

Main.cs

```
    public static class EnvioEmail
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main()
    {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new EnvioEmailAutomatico()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não vi nada relacionado ao envio de e-mail em seu código, você ainda não implementou essa parte? O erro acontece ao debugar ou ao iniciar o serviço no windows?

Comment: Eu retirei a parte do envio de e-mail. Fiz um serviço exatamente igual esta no código e tentei executar, porém exibe o mesmo erro 1053 ao inicializar ele.

Comment: Na máquina local o serviço roda, no servidor não

Comment: Hmmm, verificou se a conta para execução do serviço tem o privilégio necessário? o erro 1053 também pode estar relacionado a firewall, mas isso só faria sentido se a versão que está publicando no servidor estiver tentando conectar ao smpt em outro ambiente.

Comment: Testei com o usuário administrador, local, meu...Não funcionou. Entendi. Falei com o pessoal da infra e eles irão reiniciar o servidor